# How to pick two folders in existing repository and make new remote repository

Tags: git

Existing repository in my computer is like this.

```
Parent
  └ A/
  └ B/
  └ C/
  └ D/
  └ .git
  └ .gitignore
```

I want to pick two folders 'C' and 'D', and push it to new remote repository on github.

Existing repository can ignore 'C' and 'D', but I want to keep this folder hierarchy.

I searched 'submodule' or 'subtree', but they seem to work on just single subfolders, not two folders 'C', and 'D'.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git filter-repo` tool: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/

```
git filter-repo --path C/ --path D/
```